Entity Framework Core : can't find table in Sqlite database
I'm currently working on a project where I need to request data from a SQLite database. My workspace is organized into two separate projects: one for the database and one for the service.
I've created a database that includes a table named Users and I've populated it with some data. However, when I try to query the Users table, I keep encountering the following error:

Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Users'

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days now, and I'm certain that my code is set up correctly.
I’ve double-checked the database path and ensured that the Users table exists within the database file using an SQLite browser.
Can anyone help me figure out what might be going wrong here? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help.
Project Structure
Microservice
|
Microservice.Database
|   |UserDbContext.cs
|   |users.db
|
|Microservice.UserService
|   |appsettings.json
|   |Program.cs

Exception:

Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Users'
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microservice.UserService.UserService.GetAll() in C:\Users\ljhha\Documents\RnD\ProjectSetup\Microservice\Microservice.UserService\UserService.cs:line 11
at Microservice.UserService.Controllers.UsersController.GetAsync() in C:\Users\ljhha\Documents\RnD\ProjectSetup\Microservice\Microservice.UserService\Controllers\UsersController.cs:line 27
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

UserDbContext.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microservice.Database.Entities;

namespace Microservice.Database
{
    public class UsersDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User>? Users { get; set; }

        public UsersDbContext() 
        { 
            // generate migrations, you need this default constructor          
        }

        public UsersDbContext(DbContextOptions<UsersDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            // Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=users.db");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            SeedData.Seed(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}

Microservice.Database.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.20">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.0">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

appsettings.json:
{
    "ConnectionStrings": 
    {
        "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=..\Microservice.Database\users.db"
    },
    "Logging": 
    {
        "LogLevel": 
        {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Microservice.UserService\Program.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microservice.Database;
using Microservice.UserService;
using Microservice.UserService.Mappers;
using AutoMapper;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.services
                .AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
                .AddDbContext<UsersDbContext>(options =>options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Microservice.UserService\Microservice.UserService.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.20">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Microservice.Database\Microservice.Database.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>


Edit the Connection String

Database.EnsureCreate();

Different version of Entity Framework Core

Check if the database has the table



Are you sure you're opening the correct database? SQLite is a file-based database. When you debug your application the local folder is bin/Debug or bin/Release, not the project root. ..\Microservice.Database\users.db is a relative path looking for the database in bin\Microservice.Database

I believe I am correct, as there is no .db file in the bin\Debug folder, and I haven't found any examples online that follow this method. I also tried using multiple connection strings absolute and relative, to access the database file, but nothing has worked.

SQLite works, as thousands of .NET developers can verify. Your code doesn't. You need to find why your code doesn't work, not bugs in SQLite. You used a relative path, ..\Microservice.Database\users.db. That's relative to the execution folder, not the project folder. Try using Path.GetAbsolutePath and log the real folder to see what the application is really trying to do.

there is no .db file precisely, and thus no table

After the code tests you provided, I reproduce your issue, the reason is that the database actually opened by EF is most likely not the file you opened in DB Browser. SQLite uses the current working directory of the process, which can be different from the source directory if started in IIS or another server, and the working directory must be manually made the root directory of the project:
1.In Solution Explorer, right click the UserService project and then select Properties.
2.Select the Debug tab in the left pane.
3.Set Working directory to the database project directory.
4.Save the changes.


